# Проверка текста на наличие соответсвий

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

Как выполнить проверку кода на наличие соответствий ?
Допустим есть php код

```
<?PHP 
function who_is_it($sName)
{
   if($sName=="EuGen")  echo("Да, это я");
   elseif($sName=="Valenok")  echo("Теперь я точно уверен, это Valenok");
   elseif($sName=="Champion") echo("Это тоже наш автор, Champion");
   else  echo("Я запутался..");
}
// основная программа
$val = 'Valenok';        who_is_it($val); 
$eu = 'EuGen';           who_is_it($eu);
$ch = 'Champion';        who_is_it($ch);
$unknown = 'Гость';      who_is_it($unknown);
echo 'ы'.$val.'ы';
?>
```

Который находиться в textarea
и если в этом коде будет найдено слово "запутался" то необходимо показать кнопку "далее"
Пример моего кода

```
    <script>

var delay;

// Initialize CodeMirror editor with a nice html5 canvas demo.
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('code'), {
  mode: 'application/x-httpd-php',
  theme: "material",
  lineNumbers: true,
  viewportMargin: Infinity,
  styleActiveLine: true,
  tabMode: 'indent',
  matchBrackets: true,
  lineWrapping: true,
  autofocus: true
});

 editor.on("change", function() {
        clearTimeout(delay);
        delay = setTimeout(updatePreview, 14);
      });
      function updatePreview() {
        var previewFrame = document.getElementById('preview');
        var preview =  previewFrame.contentDocument ||  previewFrame.contentWindow.document;
        preview.open();
        preview.write(editor.getValue());
        preview.close();
      }

          setTimeout(updatePreview, 100);

          editor.on('update', function(instance){
            $("#code").val(instance.getValue());
        });
RegExp.escape = function(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}

function InsertText(){
    var str = RegExp.escape(editor.getValue()); 
    var res = str.replace(new RegExp(RegExp.escape('<?echo htmlspecialchars_decode($check_less, ENT_QUOTES)?>'), 'g'), "");
    var re = RegExp.escape(res);


if(re.test(editor.getValue())){
    $("#next").show();
}
else{
    $("#next").hide();
   }

}
</script>
```

До того как я ввел функцию text для реплейса, проверка работала нормально но были проблемы со спец. символами, теперь проблемы со спец. символами нет, но при выполнении проверки появляется ошибка "re.test is not a function"
Как это исправить ?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, проблема в том, что вы дважды используете `RegExp.escape`.
Сначала на контенте, из которого создаете регулярное выражение `res`, а затем второй раз, когда присваиваете значение переменной `re`.

Вы превращаете регулярное выражение в обычную строку, а у нее нет метода `.test()`.

Вам следует пересмотреть метод `RegExp.escape()`, если одного его прохода недостаточно для экранирования спец. символов.